# Best way to extend the the calendar with codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I'm searching for an easy way to extend the codeigniter calendar in the following way:
I have a start and an end date. The days between are coherent. For example: I want to change the background color of the cells from 11.11.2011 to 15.11.2011 (start date and end date came from the database). In the cell with the start date I want add an additional background image (this works fine at this time). How did I have to extend the template?

Best regards ...

Answer (score 0):

By ammending the template you send across to the Calendar Class - http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/calendar.html - you can use the {cal_cell_content_today}{/cal_cell_content_today} tags to find out if there is an event for that particular day and then do as you wish. Maybe add a class or inline styles. Whatever works better for you.

The only drawback I've had with this is that you have to pass the days individually. So for your example, you'd need to send the following dates:

- 11.11.2011
- 12.11.2011
- 13.11.2011
- 14.11.2011
- 15.11.2011